# Setter for anything in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setter

I have an object, let's call it `obj`, it looks like this:

```
const obj = {
  key: "value"
}
```

Now I want to do something when a property is set. I heard about setters,
that I can use by doing:

```
const obj = {
   set key(e) {
     console.log("Property key has been set!")
   }
}
```

But I want to do this, for any property... Like instead of only for key, it would be for anything, example:

```
obj.SomeKey = "value"
```

Should log `"Property key has been set!"`
and it would be the same for any property...
Is there a way in JavaScript to do this? Thanks

Comment: Read on [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a ES6 [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which allows you to modify the `set` method like so:

```js
const obj = {
  key: "value"
};

const objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  set: (obj, prop, v) => {
    obj[prop] = v;
    console.log("do something");
  }
});

objProxy.name = "foo";
console.log(objProxy); // Proxy now has name attribute
console.log(obj); // And so does the original object
```